# jQuery find and filter dates

Tags: jquery, date, filter

I have a regular calendar in which the td's have a click event handler. I return the value of the table cell(1-31). I also have a list of events - only 1 per day

```
<div class="event">
<h2>the title</h2>
<div class="date"> October <span class="day">23</span> 2012 </div>
</div>
```

What I need to do is when I click on the day on the calendar filter out the events.

Comment: Please provide more data with jquery and FIDDLE.

Comment: you should provide some more code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".day").on("click",function(){
  $.get("getevents.php?day="+$(this).text(),function(data){
    $("#showing div").html(data);
             //or
    $(".event").find("h2").text(data);   
  })
 })
})
```